Fold similar columns into structs in polars
I have a wide polars data frame that follows a very consistent pattern



x-latest
x-mean
x-std
y-latest
y-mean
y-std
z-latest
z-mean
z-std
...

















And I am looking to "fold it" into structs



x-stats
y-stats
z-stats
...











I can do this in a python list comprehension as such:
cols = ['x', 'y', 'z', ...]

df.select(*[

    pl.struct(
        latest=f'{c}-latest', 
        mean=f'{c}-mean', 
        std=f'{c}-std'
     ).alias(f'{c}-stats') 
   
    for c in cols]
)

But I may be missing the existence of some polars functionality - some "match by prefix fold" or similar.
Does this exist?

I think your solution is totally fine as is. The only thing you could simplify is the unpacking of the list. You can get rid of it and simply pass the generator expression to df.select.

I don't think there's such a functionality in polars, you could generalize your expression a bit more though:
sch = [s.split('-') for s in df.schema.keys()] # split columns by '-'

cols = set(x[0] for x in sch)                  # list of unique prefixes
stats = set(x[1] for x in sch)                 # list of unique suffixes

df.select(
    pl.struct(
        pl.col(f'{c}-{s}').alias(s) for s in stats
     ).alias(f'{c}-stats')
    for c in cols
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ y-stats   ┆ x-stats   │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ struct[2] ┆ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ {7,6}     ┆ {5,1}     │
│ {5,5}     ┆ {4,2}     │
│ {6,6}     ┆ {3,3}     │
└───────────┴───────────┘

